# Why does my terminal open with "Basic" settings

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a laptop running OS X 10.9.2 and 10.7.5.

On both I use Terminal extensively.

I have Terminal set up open with Homebrew settings on startup on both 10.7 and 10.9.  The issue occurs when I close all open tabs and Terminal windows with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, so that the app is still running but there are no windows visible.

The behaviour of Terminal on 10.7.5 is as I would expect. When I open a new window with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> the new terminal window opens with "Homebrew" settings.

The behaviour with 10.9.2 is not what I would expect (maybe I need to have it explained).  Again if all windows are closed but Terminal is left active and I start a new window using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> the new window has "Basic" settings instead of "Homebrew". I have checked this behaviour and it is consistent on both a MBP and Mini I have running with Maverics.

Is this behaviour normal?

If so, is there a way to modify it, so that Maverics behaves like 10.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just missed a setting. The "Default" button makes whatever you have selected in the Preferences menu the default.

[image: Terminal prefs]
(Selected in red)

<strike>I do find it kind of annoying that you can't set Terminal to just open with the default settings, so you have to change it in two places.</strike> **edit** - turns out I'm completely wrong, it does change the Startup automatically if you change the default. I guess I had the same problem as OP :P

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last sentence — what's the second place it has to be changed?

Comment: @grgarside The [startup settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk6eN.png).

Comment: @0942v8653 These settings appear to be linked on my system — changing one changes the other.

Comment: @grgarside Huh, never noticed that. I think that's new (at least it doesn't exist in Snow Leopard)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'm running OS X 10.9.3. Maybe someone between these OSs could say whether this is true for their version?